# When list of search results is an object and one is chosen, ngtypeahead input shows [object][object]

Tags: ng-bootstrap

```
Model: {
  "strText": "AngularJs",
  "strSectionPath": "favoriteNpmLibraries",
  "strTabPath": "angularJs"
  }
```

If user choses this search result, then input box shows [object][object].

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Use inputFormatter to choose what you want to display from an object.
In view:
`<input [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [inputFormatter]="formatter" />`

In component:
`formatter = (x: {strText: string}) => x.strText;`

It displays value of strText property of your object.

Let me know if you need more info.